# Unused argument (pretty = TRUE) in R

Tags: r

I had this working completely fine and changed nothing, but when I ran it again I got the error code:

Error in toJSON(json_data, pretty = TRUE) :
unused argument (pretty = TRUE)

in reference to the line below. When I `print(json_data)` everything prints out fine so I know it has nothing to do with the data. I'm pretty lost, any ideas? I reinstalled all of the packages I am using (`jsonlite`, `rjson`, etc.) and as far as my research shows `pretty = TRUE` should be working just fine. My code is below:

```
x <- toJSON(json_data, pretty = TRUE)
```

Here is an example of the data:

```
$`@context`
[1] "context.jsonld"

$archiveType
[1] "Marine sediment"

$dataSetName
[1] "2005-804.devernal.2013"

$pub
$pub[[1]]
$pub[[1]]$pubYear
[1] "2013"
```

Comment: There are three packages with a function named `toJSON()`.  Which one are you using?

Comment: you could all save us a bit of work by giving us a bit of your data as well. You could also pinpoint the error via `> jsoncars <- toJSON(mtcars, pretty=TRUE)` which I can run fine under `jsonlite`

Comment: I'm guessing you have loaded all the libraries in your environment so when you call `toJSON` its just using the last one loaded instead of your intended one. You can specify which one one by using `PACKAGE::toJSON` if there is a need to load them all.